# Submitting form using http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

I have a modal in my html code:

```
<div id="submitSuccess" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content alert-success">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">File A Defect</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Submitted successfully!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="submitmodal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitForm()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then I have this in my js script which validate, if title and description is ok, I want to first show the above modal,

```
 $("#submitForm").validate({
     rules: {
         title: {
             required: true
         },
         description: {
             required: true,
         },
     },

     errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
            return true;
          },

     submitHandler: function(form) {
         $('#submitSuccess').modal("show");

         if(('#submitmodal').trigger( "click" )){
        form.submit();
         }else{
             event.preventDefault();
         }
     },
 });
```

What I want is when the modal show, you need to click first the

```
<button id="submitmodal" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
```

before submitting the form

Comment: `trigger("click")` sends a click event to the submit button, it's not a test of any kind.

Comment: You need to put a click handler on the modal's submit button that submits the form.

Comment: Where are your `<form></form>` tags?  The jQuery Validate plugin only works within a `<form>` container, nothing else.  You absolutely do not need a `click` handler within the `submitHandler` of the plugin.... this is all automatic as per the plugin.  If your button is not a `type="submit"`, then the `click` handler has to be **outside** of `.validate()` entirely.